# Change the item index in an arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist

I have a `List<POJO>` with three Packagenames. So if I "click" on the second item `com.app.2` I want that the index is 0. I don't want to replace it, I want to change the index only.

For example:

```
(0) com.app.1
(1) com.app.2
(2) com.app.3
```

*Click on the second item* (from above)

```
(0) com.app.2
(1) com.app.1
(2) com.app.3
```

*Click on the third item* (from above)

```
(0) com.app.3
(1) com.app.2
(2) com.app.1
```

*Click on the second item* (from above)

```
(0) com.app.2
(1) com.app.3
(2) com.app.1
```

Well I thought `List<POJO>.set(i,Object)` will do it, but it's doing something like this:

```
(0) com.app.1
(1) com.app.2
(2) com.app.3
```

*Click on the second item* (from above)

```
(0) com.app.2
(1) com.app.2
(2) com.app.3
```

So it is replacing the item and thats not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try combining `remove(int)` with `add(int, E)`:

```
POJO tmp = list.remove(i); // the clicked index
list.add(0, tmp);
```

In this particular case, everything works perfectly. However, if you were adding to a position other than `0` you'd have to keep in mind that everything in the list after the removed item will "slide" up one position.